# Get label of form's select option instead if the value using javascript

Tags: jquery, forms, select

HTML:

```
<select id="provider" class="chzn-select" name="provider">
    <option value="0">Please Select A Provider</option>
    <optgroup label="Canada">
        <option value="2043">Bell</option>
        <option value="2049">Fido</option>
        <option value="2061">Koodo Mobile</option>
        <option value="2056">Mobilicity</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

JAVA SCRIPT:

`$('#provider').val()` Gives me the value such as "2043" if Bell is selected, how do i get the label text such as "Bell" if Bell is selected.

Comment: `$('#provider :selected').text()` Should give you that.

Comment: don't forget to close the `</optgroup>

Answer (score 3):

You can find the selected option using [selected-selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) and then read its text

```
$('#provider option:selected').text()
```